# How to align this long equation which out put from Mathematica

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, wolfram-mathematica

I use *Mathematica*,  and use the command TeXForm  from *Mathematica*, I get

[image]

```
    \{\{x\to -19,y\to 4,z\to 11,t\to -14,m\to
       11,n\to 19\},\{x\to -19,y\to 4,z\to 11,t\to
       19,m\to 11,n\to -14\},\{x\to -16,y\to -6,z\to
       17,t\to -6,m\to 2,n\to 21\},\{x\to -16,y\to
       -2,z\to 5,t\to 19,m\to 14,n\to -8\},\{x\to
       -16,y\to -2,z\to 14,t\to -8,m\to 5,n\to
       19\},\{x\to -16,y\to 13,z\to 2,t\to -17,m\to
       17,n\to 13\},\{x\to -16,y\to 13,z\to 17,t\to
       13,m\to 2,n\to -17\},\{x\to -10,y\to 16,z\to
       -4,t\to -14,m\to 17,n\to 7\},\{x\to -10,y\to
       16,z\to 17,t\to 7,m\to -4,n\to -14\},\{x\to
       -8,y\to -14,z\to -8,t\to 19,m\to 19,n\to
       4\},\{x\to -8,y\to -14,z\to 19,t\to 4,m\to
       -8,n\to 19\},\{x\to -8,y\to 6,z\to 4,t\to
       -6,m\to 7,n\to 9\},\{x\to -8,y\to 6,z\to
       7,t\to 9,m\to 4,n\to -6\},\{x\to -8,y\to
       19,z\to -8,t\to -14,m\to 19,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       -8,y\to 19,z\to 19,t\to 4,m\to -8,n\to
       -14\},\{x\to -7,y\to -5,z\to -1,t\to 13,m\to
       11,n\to 1\},\{x\to -7,y\to -5,z\to 11,t\to
       1,m\to -1,n\to 13\},\{x\to -5,y\to 4,z\to
       4,t\to -2,m\to 4,n\to 7\},\{x\to -5,y\to
       4,z\to 4,t\to 7,m\to 4,n\to -2\},\{x\to
       -4,y\to -14,z\to -10,t\to 16,m\to 17,n\to
       7\},\{x\to -4,y\to -14,z\to 17,t\to 7,m\to
       -10,n\to 16\},\{x\to -4,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to
       7,m\to 5,n\to 1\},\{x\to -4,y\to 1,z\to
       5,t\to 1,m\to 2,n\to 7\},\{x\to -4,y\to
       6,z\to 2,t\to -3,m\to 5,n\to 6\},\{x\to
       -4,y\to 6,z\to 5,t\to 6,m\to 2,n\to
       -3\},\{x\to -2,y\to 0,z\to 1,t\to 6,m\to
       4,n\to 3\},\{x\to -2,y\to 0,z\to 4,t\to
       3,m\to 1,n\to 6\},\{x\to -1,y\to -2,z\to
       -1,t\to 7,m\to 5,n\to 4\},\{x\to -1,y\to
       -2,z\to 5,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       -1,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to
       4\},\{x\to -1,y\to 3,z\to 2,t\to 3,m\to
       2,n\to 3\},\{x\to -1,y\to 4,z\to 2,t\to
       1,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to -1,y\to 4,z\to
       2,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 1\},\{x\to -1,y\to
       7,z\to -1,t\to -2,m\to 5,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       -1,y\to 7,z\to 5,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       -2\},\{x\to -1,y\to 13,z\to -7,t\to -5,m\to
       11,n\to 1\},\{x\to -1,y\to 13,z\to 11,t\to
       1,m\to -7,n\to -5\},\{x\to 1,y\to 1,z\to
       1,t\to 4,m\to 1,n\to 4\},\{x\to 1,y\to 3,z\to
       1,t\to 3,m\to 1,n\to 3\},\{x\to 1,y\to 4,z\to
       1,t\to 1,m\to 1,n\to 4\},\{x\to 1,y\to 4,z\to
       1,t\to 4,m\to 1,n\to 1\},\{x\to 1,y\to 6,z\to
       -2,t\to 0,m\to 4,n\to 3\},\{x\to 1,y\to
       6,z\to 4,t\to 3,m\to -2,n\to 0\},\{x\to
       2,y\to -17,z\to -16,t\to 13,m\to 17,n\to
       13\},\{x\to 2,y\to -17,z\to 17,t\to 13,m\to
       -16,n\to 13\},\{x\to 2,y\to -3,z\to -4,t\to
       6,m\to 5,n\to 6\},\{x\to 2,y\to -3,z\to
       5,t\to 6,m\to -4,n\to 6\},\{x\to 2,y\to
       1,z\to -1,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       2,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 2,y\to 3,z\to -1,t\to 3,m\to
       2,n\to 3\},\{x\to 2,y\to 3,z\to 2,t\to 3,m\to
       -1,n\to 3\},\{x\to 2,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to
       1,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to 2,y\to 4,z\to
       -1,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 1\},\{x\to 2,y\to
       4,z\to 2,t\to 1,m\to -1,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       2,y\to 4,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       1\},\{x\to 2,y\to 7,z\to -4,t\to 1,m\to
       5,n\to 1\},\{x\to 2,y\to 7,z\to 5,t\to 1,m\to
       -4,n\to 1\},\{x\to 4,y\to -6,z\to -8,t\to
       6,m\to 7,n\to 9\},\{x\to 4,y\to -6,z\to
       7,t\to 9,m\to -8,n\to 6\},\{x\to 4,y\to
       -2,z\to -5,t\to 4,m\to 4,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       4,y\to -2,z\to 4,t\to 7,m\to -5,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 4,y\to 3,z\to -2,t\to 0,m\to
       1,n\to 6\},\{x\to 4,y\to 3,z\to 1,t\to 6,m\to
       -2,n\to 0\},\{x\to 4,y\to 7,z\to -5,t\to
       4,m\to 4,n\to -2\},\{x\to 4,y\to 7,z\to
       4,t\to -2,m\to -5,n\to 4\},\{x\to 5,y\to
       1,z\to -4,t\to 1,m\to 2,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       5,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 7,m\to -4,n\to
       1\},\{x\to 5,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to -2,m\to
       -1,n\to 7\},\{x\to 5,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to
       7,m\to -1,n\to -2\},\{x\to 5,y\to 6,z\to
       -4,t\to 6,m\to 2,n\to -3\},\{x\to 5,y\to
       6,z\to 2,t\to -3,m\to -4,n\to 6\},\{x\to
       5,y\to 19,z\to -16,t\to -2,m\to 14,n\to
       -8\},\{x\to 5,y\to 19,z\to 14,t\to -8,m\to
       -16,n\to -2\},\{x\to 7,y\to 9,z\to -8,t\to
       6,m\to 4,n\to -6\},\{x\to 7,y\to 9,z\to
       4,t\to -6,m\to -8,n\to 6\},\{x\to 11,y\to
       -14,z\to -19,t\to 4,m\to 11,n\to 19\},\{x\to
       11,y\to -14,z\to 11,t\to 19,m\to -19,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 11,y\to 1,z\to -7,t\to -5,m\to
       -1,n\to 13\},\{x\to 11,y\to 1,z\to -1,t\to
       13,m\to -7,n\to -5\},\{x\to 11,y\to 19,z\to
       -19,t\to 4,m\to 11,n\to -14\},\{x\to 11,y\to
       19,z\to 11,t\to -14,m\to -19,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       14,y\to -8,z\to -16,t\to -2,m\to 5,n\to
       19\},\{x\to 14,y\to -8,z\to 5,t\to 19,m\to
       -16,n\to -2\},\{x\to 17,y\to -6,z\to -16,t\to
       -6,m\to 2,n\to 21\},\{x\to 17,y\to 7,z\to
       -10,t\to 16,m\to -4,n\to -14\},\{x\to 17,y\to
       7,z\to -4,t\to -14,m\to -10,n\to 16\},\{x\to
       17,y\to 13,z\to -16,t\to 13,m\to 2,n\to
       -17\},\{x\to 17,y\to 13,z\to 2,t\to -17,m\to
       -16,n\to 13\},\{x\to 19,y\to 4,z\to -8,t\to
       -14,m\to -8,n\to 19\},\{x\to 19,y\to 4,z\to
       -8,t\to 19,m\to -8,n\to -14\}\}
```

And this is another code from *Mathematica*

```
{{3, 4, 5}, {5, 12, 13}, {7, 24, 25}, {8, 15, 17}, {9, 12, 15}, {9, 
  40, 41}, {12, 35, 37}, {15, 20, 25}, {15, 36, 39}, {20, 21, 
  29}, {21, 28, 35}, {24, 45, 51}, {27, 36, 45}, {28, 45, 53}, {33, 
  44, 55}, {6, 8, 10}, {10, 24, 26}, {12, 16, 20}, {14, 48, 50}, {16, 
  30, 34}, {18, 24, 30}, {20, 48, 52}, {24, 32, 40}, {30, 40, 
  50}, {36, 48, 60}, {40, 42, 58}}
```

How to align this equations in TeX?

Comment: Do you need some special alignment?

Comment: I use Mathematica and convert them to tex many times. Therefore, if there is a general method is very good. Please help me.

Comment: Of course we will try to help you,  but first you need to tell us the desired overall aspect. How would you like the expression to look like?  Do you expect some kind of alignment of the subformulas?

Comment: You can do any way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This allows to split at each `\},` without changing the Mathematica provided code in any way. Page break are done automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{adjustwidth}{3em}{3em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\}{\@ifnextchar,\@splittablecomma\rbrace}
\newcommand\@splittablecomma[1]{\rbrace,\penalty0 }
\renewcommand\{{\@ifnextchar\{{\llap{$\lbrace$}}\lbrace}
\makeatother
$
\{\{x\to -19,y\to 4,z\to 11,t\to -14,m\to
       11,n\to 19\},\{x\to -19,y\to 4,z\to 11,t\to
       19,m\to 11,n\to -14\},\{x\to -16,y\to -6,z\to
       17,t\to -6,m\to 2,n\to 21\},\{x\to -16,y\to
       -2,z\to 5,t\to 19,m\to 14,n\to -8\},\{x\to
       -16,y\to -2,z\to 14,t\to -8,m\to 5,n\to
       19\},\{x\to -16,y\to 13,z\to 2,t\to -17,m\to
       17,n\to 13\},\{x\to -16,y\to 13,z\to 17,t\to
       13,m\to 2,n\to -17\},\{x\to -10,y\to 16,z\to
       -4,t\to -14,m\to 17,n\to 7\},\{x\to -10,y\to
       16,z\to 17,t\to 7,m\to -4,n\to -14\},\{x\to
       -8,y\to -14,z\to -8,t\to 19,m\to 19,n\to
       4\},\{x\to -8,y\to -14,z\to 19,t\to 4,m\to
       -8,n\to 19\},\{x\to -8,y\to 6,z\to 4,t\to
       -6,m\to 7,n\to 9\},\{x\to -8,y\to 6,z\to
       7,t\to 9,m\to 4,n\to -6\},\{x\to -8,y\to
       19,z\to -8,t\to -14,m\to 19,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       -8,y\to 19,z\to 19,t\to 4,m\to -8,n\to
       -14\},\{x\to -7,y\to -5,z\to -1,t\to 13,m\to
       11,n\to 1\},\{x\to -7,y\to -5,z\to 11,t\to
       1,m\to -1,n\to 13\},\{x\to -5,y\to 4,z\to
       4,t\to -2,m\to 4,n\to 7\},\{x\to -5,y\to
       4,z\to 4,t\to 7,m\to 4,n\to -2\},\{x\to
       -4,y\to -14,z\to -10,t\to 16,m\to 17,n\to
       7\},\{x\to -4,y\to -14,z\to 17,t\to 7,m\to
       -10,n\to 16\},\{x\to -4,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to
       7,m\to 5,n\to 1\},\{x\to -4,y\to 1,z\to
       5,t\to 1,m\to 2,n\to 7\},\{x\to -4,y\to
       6,z\to 2,t\to -3,m\to 5,n\to 6\},\{x\to
       -4,y\to 6,z\to 5,t\to 6,m\to 2,n\to
       -3\},\{x\to -2,y\to 0,z\to 1,t\to 6,m\to
       4,n\to 3\},\{x\to -2,y\to 0,z\to 4,t\to
       3,m\to 1,n\to 6\},\{x\to -1,y\to -2,z\to
       -1,t\to 7,m\to 5,n\to 4\},\{x\to -1,y\to
       -2,z\to 5,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       -1,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to
       4\},\{x\to -1,y\to 3,z\to 2,t\to 3,m\to
       2,n\to 3\},\{x\to -1,y\to 4,z\to 2,t\to
       1,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to -1,y\to 4,z\to
       2,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 1\},\{x\to -1,y\to
       7,z\to -1,t\to -2,m\to 5,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       -1,y\to 7,z\to 5,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       -2\},\{x\to -1,y\to 13,z\to -7,t\to -5,m\to
       11,n\to 1\},\{x\to -1,y\to 13,z\to 11,t\to
       1,m\to -7,n\to -5\},\{x\to 1,y\to 1,z\to
       1,t\to 4,m\to 1,n\to 4\},\{x\to 1,y\to 3,z\to
       1,t\to 3,m\to 1,n\to 3\},\{x\to 1,y\to 4,z\to
       1,t\to 1,m\to 1,n\to 4\},\{x\to 1,y\to 4,z\to
       1,t\to 4,m\to 1,n\to 1\},\{x\to 1,y\to 6,z\to
       -2,t\to 0,m\to 4,n\to 3\},\{x\to 1,y\to
       6,z\to 4,t\to 3,m\to -2,n\to 0\},\{x\to
       2,y\to -17,z\to -16,t\to 13,m\to 17,n\to
       13\},\{x\to 2,y\to -17,z\to 17,t\to 13,m\to
       -16,n\to 13\},\{x\to 2,y\to -3,z\to -4,t\to
       6,m\to 5,n\to 6\},\{x\to 2,y\to -3,z\to
       5,t\to 6,m\to -4,n\to 6\},\{x\to 2,y\to
       1,z\to -1,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       2,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 2,y\to 3,z\to -1,t\to 3,m\to
       2,n\to 3\},\{x\to 2,y\to 3,z\to 2,t\to 3,m\to
       -1,n\to 3\},\{x\to 2,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to
       1,m\to 2,n\to 4\},\{x\to 2,y\to 4,z\to
       -1,t\to 4,m\to 2,n\to 1\},\{x\to 2,y\to
       4,z\to 2,t\to 1,m\to -1,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       2,y\to 4,z\to 2,t\to 4,m\to -1,n\to
       1\},\{x\to 2,y\to 7,z\to -4,t\to 1,m\to
       5,n\to 1\},\{x\to 2,y\to 7,z\to 5,t\to 1,m\to
       -4,n\to 1\},\{x\to 4,y\to -6,z\to -8,t\to
       6,m\to 7,n\to 9\},\{x\to 4,y\to -6,z\to
       7,t\to 9,m\to -8,n\to 6\},\{x\to 4,y\to
       -2,z\to -5,t\to 4,m\to 4,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       4,y\to -2,z\to 4,t\to 7,m\to -5,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 4,y\to 3,z\to -2,t\to 0,m\to
       1,n\to 6\},\{x\to 4,y\to 3,z\to 1,t\to 6,m\to
       -2,n\to 0\},\{x\to 4,y\to 7,z\to -5,t\to
       4,m\to 4,n\to -2\},\{x\to 4,y\to 7,z\to
       4,t\to -2,m\to -5,n\to 4\},\{x\to 5,y\to
       1,z\to -4,t\to 1,m\to 2,n\to 7\},\{x\to
       5,y\to 1,z\to 2,t\to 7,m\to -4,n\to
       1\},\{x\to 5,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to -2,m\to
       -1,n\to 7\},\{x\to 5,y\to 4,z\to -1,t\to
       7,m\to -1,n\to -2\},\{x\to 5,y\to 6,z\to
       -4,t\to 6,m\to 2,n\to -3\},\{x\to 5,y\to
       6,z\to 2,t\to -3,m\to -4,n\to 6\},\{x\to
       5,y\to 19,z\to -16,t\to -2,m\to 14,n\to
       -8\},\{x\to 5,y\to 19,z\to 14,t\to -8,m\to
       -16,n\to -2\},\{x\to 7,y\to 9,z\to -8,t\to
       6,m\to 4,n\to -6\},\{x\to 7,y\to 9,z\to
       4,t\to -6,m\to -8,n\to 6\},\{x\to 11,y\to
       -14,z\to -19,t\to 4,m\to 11,n\to 19\},\{x\to
       11,y\to -14,z\to 11,t\to 19,m\to -19,n\to
       4\},\{x\to 11,y\to 1,z\to -7,t\to -5,m\to
       -1,n\to 13\},\{x\to 11,y\to 1,z\to -1,t\to
       13,m\to -7,n\to -5\},\{x\to 11,y\to 19,z\to
       -19,t\to 4,m\to 11,n\to -14\},\{x\to 11,y\to
       19,z\to 11,t\to -14,m\to -19,n\to 4\},\{x\to
       14,y\to -8,z\to -16,t\to -2,m\to 5,n\to
       19\},\{x\to 14,y\to -8,z\to 5,t\to 19,m\to
       -16,n\to -2\},\{x\to 17,y\to -6,z\to -16,t\to
       -6,m\to 2,n\to 21\},\{x\to 17,y\to 7,z\to
       -10,t\to 16,m\to -4,n\to -14\},\{x\to 17,y\to
       7,z\to -4,t\to -14,m\to -10,n\to 16\},\{x\to
       17,y\to 13,z\to -16,t\to 13,m\to 2,n\to
       -17\},\{x\to 17,y\to 13,z\to 2,t\to -17,m\to
       -16,n\to 13\},\{x\to 19,y\to 4,z\to -8,t\to
       -14,m\to -8,n\to 19\},\{x\to 19,y\to 4,z\to
       -8,t\to 19,m\to -8,n\to -14\}\}
$
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank egreg very much. Please help me in this case. My code in Mathematica is

Comment: Please help me another case. I have just edited my question.

Comment: @egreg Awesome! `:)`